# How do I deserialize objects added to a RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, serialization, io

I'm serializing (I hope) objects and adding them to a RandomAccessFile (1 object = 1 block). I need each block that I add to be just under 32KB. Although this process is completed, I can't read anything from the file. I always get a java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0000000 error.

Here's the code:

```
RandomAccessFile datafile = new RandomAccessFile("src/main/java/datafile", "rw");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

        DataBlock prevBlock = null;
        boolean blockWritten = false;
        int ID = 1;
        int i = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> sizes = new ArrayList<>();

        do {

            ArrayList<DataRecord> blockRecords = new ArrayList<>();
            int size = 0;

            do {
                DataBlock block = new DataBlock(ID, blockRecords);
                stream.writeObject(block);
                if (baos.toByteArray().length >= 32000) { //Block full

                    stream.reset();
                    baos.reset();
                    stream.writeObject(prevBlock);
                    System.out.println(prevBlock.getBlockData());
                    stream.flush();
                    datafile.seek(ID * 32000L);
                    datafile.write(baos.toByteArray());
                    prevBlock = null;
                    ID++;
                    blockWritten = true;

                } else {  //Adds more data to the block since it hasn't reached its limit yet

                    stream.reset();
                    baos.reset();
                    prevBlock = block;
                    Node currentItem = nl.item(i);
                    String name = currentItem.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
                    float latitude = Float.parseFloat(currentItem.getAttributes().getNamedItem("lat").getNodeValue());
                    float longitude = Float.parseFloat(currentItem.getAttributes().getNamedItem("lon").getNodeValue());
                    Float[] Coords = {latitude, longitude};
                    DataRecord record = new DataRecord(i + 1, name, Coords);
                    blockRecords.add(record);
                    size++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            while (!blockWritten && i < nl.getLength());

            stream.reset();
            baos.reset();
            blockWritten = false;
            sizes.add(size);
        }
        while (i < nl.getLength());
```

Tried using different kinds of input streams but all of them gave me an error. Ideally, I'd like to access the file with an offset and read the block that's there.

Comment: You need to create a new `ObjectOutputStream` per block, and ditto `ObjectInputStream` when reading. But it's hard to see the point of all this. Specifically, at best you are wasting space inside each 32k block, and at worst you are losing the benefit of serialization reference sharing every time you start a new block. Object serialization is inherently, err, serial in nature. You can't random-access it. Use a `FileOutputStream`, and a `FileInputStream` when reading.

Comment: @user207421 After that I'm supposed to access the file with an R* Tree, so that's why I want it to use random access. So I guess I should just make it without object serialization?

Comment: I would say so. You're beyond the limits of the technology.